# Count the instances of a string in a div, and remove all extra instances of that string with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, string, dom, counter

What I'm trying to do is basically keep a specific string of characters from being shown twice within a div, using jQuery.  Due to the nature of my work, I can't share the exact code, but let's say I had something like the following:

```
<div class="sample">
    blah blah blah blah a horse is a horse of course of course blah blah blah blah
    blah a horse is a horse of course of course blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
    blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah a horse is a horse of course of 
    course blah blah blah blah...
</div>
```

I don't want the div to show "a horse is a horse of course of course" any more than once, so I guess what I'd like to do is remove all extra instances of that phrase.  How would I go about doing that using jQuery?

Comment: Have you considered using regex?

Comment: Split the string into two parts: everything up to and including the first occurrence, and everything after that. Then remove the string from the second part using `.replace()`. Finally, concatenate that result to the first part and store it back in the DIV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
$('.sample:contains("a horse is a horse of course of course")').text(function () {
    var match = 0;
    var newText = $(this).text().replace(/a horse is a horse of course of course/ig, function (str) {
        match++;
        return (match==1)?str:'';
    });
    return newText;
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/nm5nzp9a/)**

Comment: That looks like it'd work perfectly.  But how would you do that if the string to be replaced were stored in a jQuery variable?  Again, I can't show the exact text, but that's the gist of it.

Comment: Should be as simple as dropping the variable in place of `"a horse is a horse of course of course"` in the above example. You may need to escape or concatenate it, but that would be a minor change.

Comment: Brilliant solution.  Thanks!